# JSON serialize/encoding in mongoengine

Tags: python, json, mongodb, serialization, mongoengine

I may be doing something stupid, but I had a serializer in mongo similar to the following:

```
from json import JSONEncoder
from pymongo.objectid import ObjectId

class MongoEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
            return str(obj)
        else:            
            return JSONEncoder.default(obj, **kwargs)
```

Now if I do:

```
obj = Model.objects().first()
json.dumps(obj, cls=MongoEncoder)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: unbound method default() must be called with JSONEncoder instance as first argument (got Allocation instance instead)
```

Did a little digging and realized that during the callback to the MongoEncoder class, the first "obj" that gets passed to default is the obj itself, not the components of the obj. At some point in the past, I had this working, but I thought it would intelligently iterate over the components of the obj passed into the json.dumps command (i.e. everything that get's passed into MongoEncoder.default is a field of the original obj, not the obj itself.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation on [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder), I've made it with the following code:

```
class MongoEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Place):
            return obj.to_dict()
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

This way I could call it passing the object itself:

```
all_places = Place.objects(foo=bar)
for p in all_places:
    place_json = json.dumps(p, cls=MongoEncoder)
```

**Edition to show to_dict method. On models.py:**

```
class Place(Document):
    name           = StringField()
    parent         = ReferenceField('self')
    ...

    def to_dict(self):

        return {
            'id': str(self.id),
            'parent': self.parent_id,
            'name': self.name,
        }
```

Comment: How does `obj` has `to_dict` method? For me such solution raises AttributeError.

Comment: Hello Serge, in the example obj is an instance of a model I called Place. I'm editing the answer so it show you how the to_dict method can be created. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your last line:

```
return JSONEncoder.default(obj, **kwargs)
```

It should be:

```
return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Standard `default` method doesn't accept kwargs ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) is docs), so you shouldn't pass them.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a pretty old question.  But I did implement a solution recently.

Basically, I do what the to_json method does on the base Document class, but do it in the encoder's default method itself.

```
from json import JSONEncoder
from bson.json_util import default
from mongoengine import Document


class MongoEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Document):
            return o.to_mongo()
        return default(o)
```

If it is MongoEngine document, it will convert it to a mongo representation, then each piece of this will be passed down to the json_utils.default function that MongoEngine uses to implement its own to_json.